# How to resample multiple files of time series data to be all the same length (same # of observations)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, time-series, resampling

I have many csv files which are of time series data (i.e. the data are sequential, however no time column exists).

I need to make all the files the same length in order to feed them into tensorflow. I could make them all the size of the file with largest length, or just use the average length of all files. -doesn't really matter-

Since the files don't have time column, I converted the index column to timedate with unit 's' and used this column in the resampling.

To give you a sample of the shape of my data, when running `df.head(3)` ,this is the result:

```
       0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7  
0  0.30467  0.45957 -0.95414  1.74687  1.42338 -0.03860  2.20401  1.44406   
1  0.27331  0.59293 -1.00874  1.74135  1.32004 -0.00701  2.20917  1.34164   
2  0.30348  0.88129 -1.05517  1.75090  1.65138 -0.03112  2.21598  1.68487
```

This is what I have tried so far to no avail:

```py
for file in files:
     df=pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
     resampled=df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index,unit='s')).resample('250ms')

resamp=pd.DataFrame(resampled)
```

I aslo tried: `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index,unit='s')).resample('250ms').asfreq()` and `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index,unit='s')).resample('250ms').asfreq().interpolate()`

None of the above gave dataframes of the same length. They all returned dfs of different lengths.

I expect the output to be resampled data such that all the files are of the same length (i.e. same number of observations) and are correctly resampled (either upsampled or downsampled).

After having resampled the files, I need to concatenate all of them to have one big file which I can then reshape to input to tensorflow.

I am new to Python so I will really appreciate support here.

Comment: Resample doesn't return a data frame. You need to tell the computer how you want to resample the data. Interpolate? Do nothing? I'm also unclear how you intend to use resample to make all your files the same length. If the files contain a different number of observations, dividing all your numbers by 4 and then interpolating data in between them will simply give a scalar multiple of the starting number of observations.

Comment: I thought resample (upsampling) would create new observations and fill them with NaN. Then I should use interpolate with a method such as ''linear'' to fill the NaN values.

Comment: If you invoke `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')).resample('250ms')` you don't get a data frame. If you then invoke on that object `interpolate` you would get a linear interpolation of the missing values. *But* with differing length inputs, you get differing length outputs. len(input) -> len(output) in R; not len(input) -> len(output) = C, if that's more explanatory

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, when I tried checking for missing values within the for loop, using ```if df.isnull.values.any() == True: print("missing values in df")```. No missing values were in any of the df.s . How do you think I should go about this?

Comment: You're testing whether there are any null values in the source CSV, before resampling.

Comment: resample does not create dataframe directly. Try resample('250ms').asfreq()

Comment: @MarkWang thank you for your reply. I tried this and indeed it returned dataframe. My main objective though is getting all the files to be of same length (i.e. same number of observations). Do you have an idea or advice on how I should go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I have reached to **making the files same size** using the following steps:

1- add date range column as index column to all files with same start and end dates.

2- resampling all files with the same resampling rate. (used trial and error to reach a resampled size that seemed good enough for my data)

3- Put a condition that if length was > desired do mean, else do interpolate

Code:

```
for i, file in enumerate (directory):
    count+=1
    df=pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    df.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1991' ,periods=len(df), end='1/1/2000'), inplace=True)
    frames_length.append(df.shape[0])

    # Resampling using 33D (33D was chosen arbitrarily with trial and error until 100 was obtained),
    # returns resampled files/movements of 100 frames each
    if df.shape[0] <100: resampled=df.resample('33D').interpolate()
    elif df.shape[0]>100: resampled=df.resample('33D').mean()
    else: break

# Check if resampled files have any nulls or NaNs
    print(resampled.isnull().any().any())
```

The above code returned files of size 100 for me.

Now what I need is to **know if resampling was correct or not**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Solved by plotting the results of the original data and resampled version of it.